# Dynamically update input to Geoserver

Tags: java, postgis, shapefile, geoserver

I am hoping someone can help me on this one as i have been trying to find the solution for a long time without success.

I have a polygon shape-file which i am displaying on browser using geoserver . I have color-coded the polygons (by creating an SLD file) based on the values of one of the attributes(say "count") in the shape-file.

My problem is that i want to update the "count" attribute (which is an integer) regularly(on a daily basis) and hence i want to reflect this change in the geoserver. I am getting the values for "count" attribute through a java service which i have up and running . But so far , i have not been able to find out a way through which i can update a single attribute(for all features) in a shape-file through java . The geoTools library helps me to read a shape-file but i could not find a way to modify an attribute using this library .

How do i go about this?Please help me with the following questions:

1. Is geoserver a correct choice for my use case?
2. Is there some way to update an attribute of a shape-file using java.?
3. Should i continue using a shape-file or move to POSTGIS?
4. Can we update attributes of features in POSTGIS using java.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you only need to show one layer, and that layer is not very big (what is the size of the shapefile?) i will convert the file to [geojson](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) and show it directly in the browser.

Geoserver is commonly used with shapefiles when the underlying data does not change. If not is common to use postgis

2. Sure. [Geotools can do it](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html). But geoserver can also do it using [WFS-T](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html). Just enable it and use POST request or the [geotools wrapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40812/java-client-for-wfs-t) to update the data.

I think that the best option is create a new user for you backed process and add a security rule that allows wfs.Transaction only for that user. You can use basic http authentication in your backed process to launch a POST http request that update the shapefile.

3. It depends. If is one shapefile and it doesn't change a log (once a day) i will probably use in this order:

geojson directly show in the browser (without geoserver) -> shapefile + geoserver -> postgis + geoserver

4. Of course. A postgis layer is only a postgresql table with a column of type geometry. You can update your table as you can update any other table in postgresql.

I can't provide a full example right now to update a shapefile with geotools but check[2](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html) this [links](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html).

- Open the shapefile as show in the access section in the second link
- Open a transaction as show in the first link
- Use the setAttribute methods of the feature instances
- Close the transaction

Comment: Using WFS-T , it is the user who can change the data . But , as an admin ,i want to do this programatically from the back-end . Will it be feasible to incorporate WFS-T in my running java service . And regarding geotools , it does allow me to create a new shapefile , but i could not find an example where it helps me modifly an existing shapefile on disk.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. I would not use a shapefile for doing this but rather a real DBMS like postgis. Shapefile are good for serving read-only datasets not for concurrent changes. Having this in mind if we are talking about a low traffic site with infrequent updates (yes, one a day is infrequent) shapefile should be ok.
2. You can modify shapefile with GeoTools as well. [This link](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) might help. Something similar can be done to update a column in Postgis or you can do it directly.
3. You can use WFS-T for the update with both Shapefile and Postgis. Notice that by default WFS-T is enabled in GeoServer and it is open to everybody, you might want to change that (i.e. enable authentication at the very least for write operations)

Hope this helps,
Simone.